# How to create a test set from multiple datasets and avoid deleting variables in the process?

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I have three datasets that I want to join in order to create a test set for being used in a supervised machine learning algorithm. The problem is that although they have some variables in common, they generally differ in number of rows and elements. I have tried to use merge() function, but however, the more I use it, the lesser number of rows I get. And at the end, I get a small dataset with a ridiculous number of rows.

I have these three datasets:

```
test_review   nºrows 22956
test_business nrows  1205
test_user     nrows  5105
```

I want to keep the original number of reviews from test_review dataset (22956) for the ultimate test_set. The idea is that the business or user that has no coincidence at the time using merge() with the review_set,it appears as Na value in the corresponding new column as a result of merging both datasets. Is there any way to make possible this?

Comment: The way to ensure that `merge` doesn't remove any rows of data is to include the argument `all=TRUE`.

Comment: Post `head(test_review); head(test_business); head(test_user)`

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(test_review,test_business,test_user)
```